# Linear gradient in SVG symbol

Tags: svg, gradient, symbols, fill, linear-gradients

I have a svg sprite with `<symbol>` trhat contains a `<linearGradient>`. I am filing a `<g>` in this same `<symbol>` with this gradient by `fill="url(#id)"`. However, when I load the `<symbol>` with `<use>` in other document, the `<linearGradient>` does not load. I can see the fill's url is referring to an absolute route instead of inside the document and not load correctly.

How can I load a `<linearGradient>` in a `<symbol>`?

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 550 90" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop offset="-1.04974" stop-color="#D8D8D8">
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="-2; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            </stop>
            <stop offset="-0.549739" stop-color="#EEEEEE">
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="-1.5; 1.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            </stop>
            <stop offset="-0.0497395" stop-color="#D8D8D8">
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="-1; 2" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g fill="url(#gradient)">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/> 
        <rect x="10" y="25" width="130" height="15" />                              
    </g>
</symbol>
```

Comment: Don't put the linearGradient in the symbol, move it outside the <symbol> element.

Answer (score 11):

For me, I had `display: none` on my `<svg>` tag that contained my `<defs>` and `<symbols>`.

Make sure that initial svg does not have `display:none` set - use `height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden` instead.

Also as noted in Waruyama's answer, make sure the `<defs>` are outside of the `<symbol>` tag.

Found this hint [here](https://github.com/w0rm/gulp-svgstore/issues/31#issuecomment-77021146).

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me crazy because I could see that it worked fine when display:none wasn't set, but I was trapped in linear (no pun intended) thinking.

Comment: Just removing ```display: none``` and not taking ```<linearGradient>``` out of ```<symbol>``` worked for me.  I had this issue only in Chrome 90

Comment: Both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` didn't work for me, only the `position`, `height` and `width` rules mad it in Safari 14.1 and Chrome 91. In Firefox 89 any solution works fine. Moving the `<defs>` tags outside the `<symbol>` tag didn't change anything, inside and outside worked both.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the comments, place the `linearGradient` outside the `symbol`.

Here is a modified example that works:

```html
<svg style="visibility:hidden; width: 0; height: 0;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="-1.04974" stop-color="#D8D8D8">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="-2; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </stop>
        <stop offset="-0.549739" stop-color="#EEEEEE">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="-1.5; 1.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </stop>
        <stop offset="-0.0497395" stop-color="#D8D8D8">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="-1; 2" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <symbol id="symbol1" viewBox="0 0 550 90" width="100%" height="100%">
      <g fill="url(#gradient)">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/> 
        <rect x="10" y="25" width="130" height="15" />                              
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs> 
</svg>


<svg width="400" height="400">
  <use xlink:href="#symbol1"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: This code does not work for me when I load the `use` in another file.